# Java aws lambda with SnapStart and springboot still take 1744ms

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, performance, aws-lambda

I have created a helloworld proyect to run springboot in a lambda with java 11. Project don´t have integrations, no bbdd or anything else. When I invoke the endpoint, the first time take about 5 seconds.

Later I began to use SnapStart, so the first invoke takes 1,7 seconds now. Still a lot of time.

Latency to my region is only 70ms.

The proyect is in github: https://github.com/nebur43/javaTest/tree/master/_AWS/holamundo-sam-aws-springboot

Cloudwatch is:

```
RESTORE_START Runtime Version: java:11.v19  Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1::runtime:XXXXXXXX
RESTORE_REPORT Restore Duration: 361.18 ms
START RequestId: XXXXXXXXX Version: 1
2023-05-25 14:34:19.456  INFO 8 --- [           main] c.n.h.controller.HolaController          : recuperando saludo...
2023-05-25 14:34:19.486  INFO 8 --- [           main] c.a.s.p.internal.LambdaContainerHandler  : x.xxx.xxx.xxx null- null [25/05/2023:14:34:18Z] "GET /saludo HTTP/1.1" 200 73 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.32.2" combined
END RequestId: XXXXXXX
REPORT RequestId: XXXXXXX   Duration: 205.50 ms Billed Duration: 430 ms Memory Size: 2048 MB    Max Memory Used: 127 MB Restore Duration: 361.18 ms Billed Restore Duration: 224 ms
```

Is it possible to reduce time less than 1 second? I see in some youtube videos lower times.

template.yaml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      CodeUri: .
      Handler: com.nebur.holamundosamawsspringboot.StreamLambdaHandler::handleRequest
      Runtime: java11
      AutoPublishAlias: production
      SnapStart:
        ApplyOn: PublishedVersions
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      MemorySize: 512      
      Environment: # More info about Env Vars: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#environment-object
        Variables:
          JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 # More info about tiered compilation https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/optimizing-aws-lambda-function-performance-for-java/      
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: ANY
```

Comment: You only get millisecond response times if your lambda is warm AND you write good code. Apparently your lambda was not warm (360ms restore time) and your code was slow as well (200ms).

Comment: Are you wrapping a controller in an AWS Lambda function?

Comment: I use SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler. Code is in github link above.